# How to remove font from text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts

I have the letter `'ᴇ'` in a text and when I have `if 'ᴇ' == 'e'` it returns `False`. How can I convert `'ᴇ'`
to `'E'`?

I tried to encode it, but when I run:

```
'ᴇ'.encode("utf-16")
>>>b'\xff\xfe\x07\x1d'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you're trying to do isn't "remove a font". You're trying to map one-or-more unicode characters into some other subset of characters. There doesn't seem to be an out-of-the-box way to do what you want, probably because there are so many different things you might "actually want".

All of the following, and *many* other distinct characters, are arguable "e"s: [ᴇ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d07/index.htm), [ꠄ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a804/index.htm), , [E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0045/index.htm), [ⅇ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2147/index.htm), [aͤ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0364/index.htm) *, [Ӭ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/04ec/index.htm), [Ꭱ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/13a1/index.htm), [e](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0065/index.htm), [Ⓔ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24ba/index.htm), [ℰ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2130/index.htm), [é](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm)

Somehow you'll have to decide which of these you want to transform, and into what, and which you'd like to leave alone. Even assuming reasonable answers exist for every question that will come up, there are simply a lot of unicode characters; don't actually try cover all cases.

Depending on the scope of the transformation you have in mind, you may be able to use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) or something funky with [codecs.register_error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error) to perform OK transformation on *many* possible inputs.

<sub>*That's actually two characters, the "a" is just an "a".</sub>